# There are pairs of rational numbers $(a,b)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, rational-numbers

There are pairs of rational numbers $(a,b)$, $a<b$, such that
$\int^b_a \frac{(2x-5)^{2020}}{x+1} \,dx \in \mathbb Q$
I do not know what to do here. I really have no idea and I am sorry for that. Could you help me, please?

Comment: What can be the form of a primitive function of this? Which part of it might break rationality?

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean @Berci.Could you detail a little more please?

Comment: If you integrate a *polynomial* with rational coefficients, you again get a polynomial with rational coefficients as primitive function, so the integral between $a,b$ will be rational.

Comment: what happens with  $\int\frac{1}{x+1}dx$?

Comment: Well, yes, that's the part you should pay attention in order to obtain a rational integral. First do a change of variables $y:=x+1$, then you only have to handle the remainder.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{(2 x-5)^{2020}}{x+1}=p_{2019}(x)+(-7)^{2020}\cdot \frac{1}{x+1}$$
integrating on $[a,b]$ we get
$$P_{2020}(b)-P_{2020}(a)+(-7)^{2020}\log\frac{b+1}{a+1}$$
the unique values that make this result a rational number are $a=b$. For any rationals $a,b$ such that $a\ne b$ we have $\log\frac{b+1}{a+1}$ irrational,  [transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number#Numbers_proven_to_be_transcendental) to be more precise.

Therefore there is no rationals $a<b$ such that the given integral is rational

Comment: Thank you!I also got to that result